# how to order a tcl procedure to use variables?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to have a very generic function and ordering it to use variables it come across from the outside.
I've tried the following (simplified code), but with no use:

```
set line "found \$find1 at \$find2"
do_search $line

proc do_search {line} {
...
if {[regexp $exp $string match find1 find2} {
     puts "$line"
}
```

However all I get is: `found $find1 at $find2` or, if I don't use the `\` before the `$find`, the value of find before I call the function.

Given that this regexp is part of a while loop while parsing a file, I can't use the values after the proc is called.

Any ideas how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your exact style, you want `subst`:

```
if {[regexp $exp $string match find1 find2} {
     puts [subst $line]
}
```

But you might consider using `format` too:

```
set fmt "found %s at %s"
do_search $fmt

proc do_search {fmt} {
...
if {[regexp $exp $string match find1 find2} {
     puts [format $fmt $find1 $find2]
}
```

Comment: the subset did the trick. exactly what i was looking for, thanks.